# When to transform GPS co-ordinates

Tags: python, gps, gis, latitude-longitude, utm

I have no real experience with GIS data, so when what I believed to be a simple problem has turned out to have more subtleties to it, I am dangerously unprepared!

I want to be able to classify a GPS position as inside/outside a polygon defined by GPS co-ordinates. It turns out this is the well-known (but not to me) [point-in-polygon problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). I have read many questions/answers on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ (and here e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892459/check-if-geo-point-is-inside-or-outside-of-polygon-in-python)).

[Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) seems a good solution, but assumes the co-ordinates are on the same cartesian plane, i.e. not GPS? So I would first need to transform my GPS points to [UTM](http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm) points.

Do I need to introduce this extra step, however, if the points being compared (i.e. the point and the polygon) are always going to be naturally within the same UTM zone. They should always be within the same town/city, so can I just leave them as GPS and use the lat/long co-ordinates in Shapely?

I also came across [this UTM-WGS84 converter](https://pypi.org/project/utm/) so I could convert my lat/long pairs using this package, and then use those UTM pairs in Shapely, but I would like to avoid any extra dependencies where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point-in-polygon already assumes a 2D restriction, and GPS coordinates are 3D. Right away, that gets you in trouble.

A simple workaround is to discard the GPS height, reducing it to 2D surface coordinates. Your next problem is that that your 2D surface is now a sphere. On a spherical surface, a polygon divides the surface in two parts, but there is no obvious "inside". There's a left-hand side and a right-hand side which follows from the order of points in the polygon, but neither side is the obvious "inside". Consider the equator as a trivial polygon - which hemisphere is "inside" the equator?

Next up is the issue of the polygon edges. By definition, these are straight, i.e. line segments. But lines on a spherical surface are weird - they're generally known as *great circles*. And any two great circles cross in exactly two points. That's not how cartesian lines behave. Worse, the equations for a great circle are not linear when expressed in GPS coordinates, because those are longitude/latitude pairs.

I can imagine that at this point you're feeling a bit confused. You might want to look at this from another side - we have a similar problem with maps. Globe maps are by definition attempts to flatten that non-flat surface. Since that's not exactly possible, you end up with [map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projections). You can also project the corner points of your polygons on such projections. And because the projections are flat, you can draw the edges on the projection. You now see the problem visually: On two different projections, identical polygons will contain different parts of the world!

So, since we agreed that in the real world, the edges of the polygons are great circles, we should really consider a projection that keeps the great circles straight. There's exactly one family of projections that has this property, and that's the [Gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection). It's a family of projections because you can pick any point as the center.

As it happens, we have one natural point to consider here: the GPS point we're considering. If you put that in the center, draw a gnomonic projection around it, project the polygon edges, and then draw the polygon, you have an exact solution.

Except that the actual earth isn't spherical. Sorry. How exact did you need the test to be, anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the informative (and disheartening) explanation! There is clearly a lot about this I don't have a clue about. I just found [this example](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/gnomon.html) of matplotlib being used for gnomonic projections, but unfortunately the basecamp lib seems an onerous install! Would my suggested GPS->UTM->Shapely be a safe bet?

Comment: I'm pretty much at a loss what you expect to achieve from moving to UTM. That's not a gnomonic projection either. It would take a decent amount of math to figure out where raw GPS coordinates are better or worse than UTM, so I won't predict where in the world UTM would work better. Just to clarify: a polygon in GPS or UTM coordinates will have bent sides in reality.

Comment: I must have understood. I thought the crux of it was that to perform point-in-polygon with something like Shapely I need to make sure the points in question are on the same cartesian plane. By transforming GPS to UTM, and only dealing with points close enough in space to fall within the same UTM grid I thought I would meet this criteria

Comment: Also, is there a straightforward way of calculating the potential errors for the different approaches? In my use-case I need to know if a person wearing a GPS sensor has crossed from a safe to an unsafe zone (defined by a polygon of GPS coordinates).

Comment: @PhilipO'Brien: The problem is that **reality** is not Cartesian, but a sphere. Now your person likely is not part of a polar expedition, so you might make things easier for yourself by putting in a semi-arbitrary restrictions like "polygons cannot extend past the polar circle, polygons are restricted to a single continent, polygons cannot cross the international date line". These are all not strictly necessary but they make things way easier. With those restrictions n place, you can probably get a reasonable enough result as long as polygons edges are <100 km.

Comment: Those restrictions probably make sense in my case. Basically, I will have people wearing sensors that should detect if they move outside safe zones in their neighbourhood/town. Thanks for the helpful explanations!

Comment: @PhilipO'Brien: That sounds like there is a legal aspect to it. Not necessarily a big deal; you just need to be able to clarify what you do. And since GPS isn't exact anyways, your solution should deal with a fuzzy border zone. For such a local area, the inherent GPS imprecision will dominate and you can get away with any reasonable flat-earth approach.